# Lock And Unlock Files Using USB Key

Tags: encryption, usb

I am looking for a way to make a set of files only able to be read when a USB key is plugged into the system. For example, if I have FILE A on my C drive and I try to open it, it will say something like "Please insert key" (The "key" being a USB drive)  Once I plug the USB drive into the computer and try to open that file, it functions normally.

It's a bit like Predator, but instead of locking the whole computer when you remove the USB drive, it only locks the files. Further, I would like this "locked" attribute to exist across systems, so that if anyone copies the files, they will not run on any other system unless they have the "key".

I worked at a company before that had such a system in place, so I know it's possible, I just have no idea how they did it.

Basically, I think what I'm trying to do is encrypt the files and put the key-file to decrypt them on the USB drive.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This might help it has a section on AES and keyfile encryption and decryption: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/scftask-4/

Answer (score 1):

TrueCrypt seems to offer the ability to use a key file with its encryption.

***As a major disclaimer TrueCrypt technically is no longer supported and may be [insecure](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsecur/opinion-truecrypt-the-nsa-and-the-myth-of-open-source-security.html).

[Here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/extreme-security-with-truecrypt--cms-19968) is a guide that you can use to add a keyfile to that encryption. You could store a key file on a USB and use that in addition to a password. There might be a more automated way to do this via detection of a USB and search for a filename but this is pretty close to what you want I think.

Comment: The [audit](http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/) of TrueCrypt discovered (six months after your reply here) that it was not maliciously compromised.  At worst, there were some honest developer mistakes which are now [out in the open](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2015/04/truecrypt-report.html).  As you point out, it's no longer maintained, and [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) is its sucessor.

Answer (score 0):

Look into GoldKey or Yubikey. I know for fact that GoldKey has something similar to what you want, they call it a [goldkey vault](https://www.goldkey.com/support/manual/managing-kryptovault-with-goldkey/). Yubikey probably has something similar, but I'm just not as familiar with their products.

Hope that helps.